# Python code isnt printing contents of txt?

Tags: python

```
elif menuOption == "2":
    with open("Hotel.txt", "a+") as file:
           print (file.read())
```

Ive tried many different ways but my python file just refuses to print the txt contents. It is writing to the file but option 2 wont read it.

```
if menuOption == "1":
  print("Please Type Your Guests Name.")
  data1 = (input() + "\n")
  for i in range (2,1000):
   file = open("hotel.txt", "a")
  file.write(data1)
  print("Please Write your Guests Room")
  data2 = (input("\n") + "\n")
  file.write(data2)
  data3 = random.randint(1, 999999)
  file.write(str (data3))
  print("Guest Added - Enjoy Your Stay.")

  print("Guest Name is:", data1)
  print("Guest Room Number Is:", data2)
  print("Your Key Code Is:", data3)
```

I want all the above information to be added to a TXT. (That works) and then be able to read it also. which won't work.
Why and how can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `a+` mode which is meant for appending to the file, you need to use `r` for reading.

Secondly I notice this

```
 for i in range (2,1000):
   file = open("hotel.txt", "a")
```

You are opening a new file handler for every iteration of the loop. Please open the file just once and then do whatever operations you need to like below.

```
with open("hotel.txt", "a") as fh:
    do your processing here...
```

This has the added advantage automatically closing the file handler for you, otherwise you need to close the file handler yourself by using `fh.close()` which you are not doing in your code.

Also a slight variation to how you are using `input`, you don't need to print the message explicitly, you can do this with `input` like this.

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `r` instead of `a+` to read from file:

```
with open("Hotel.txt", "r") as file:
```